# Which is easier: Blackberry Webworks SDK or Adobe AIR for Playbook Tablet for CRUD/WCF developement?

Tags: blackberry, air, webwork, blackberry-playbook

I want to create a 1.0 application that uses WCF calls with the Blackberry Playbook Tablet.

Which technology is easier to make a CRUD application using WCF: Webworks, or Playbook?

The WCF service is very flexible in how calls are done... javascript, soap, etc, so I just want to know what client technology will help me churn out a quick productivity application?

It would be great if you can mention what is a closer fit to my skillset as well: C#, Javascript, and to a lesser extent CSS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll probably want to go with WebWorks, which is HTML + JavaScript. Less of a learning curve for you, plus you don't need to buy any tools.

Comment: I see... so Air isn't free...

Comment: Well, the SDK is free, but most people end up using an Adobe tool like Flash Builder. I think for someone with JavaScript + HTML experience it's easier to go the WebWorks way.

Answer (score 1):

I've been finding [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/) plus WebWorks to be a great combination.